# expectation noncentral chi distribution; reference request

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, reference-request, normal-distribution

I am currently looking into the non-central chi distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi_distribution).

For my purpose, I assume that $\mathbf{Z} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{m},\mathbf{1})$, where $\mathbf{m}$ is a $d$ dimensional vector and $\mathbf{1}$ is the $d\times d$ identity matrix.
The random variable of interest is now given as $X = \Vert \mathbf{Z} \Vert_2 = \sqrt{Z_1^2 + \ldots + Z_d^2}$.

Finally I would like to compute $\mathbb{E}[X]$.
On Wikipedia we have formulas for the moments in terms of generalized Laguerre polynomials, but there is no reference included.
Do you know of any book / paper that contains the result (and a derivation)?

Thank you for your time!

---

Edit: Just to avoid confusion, I am not looking for a reference on Laguerre polynomials, but for a (citable) reference of $\mathbb{E}(X)$ for the given model.

Comment: If you read further on in Wikipedia on 'noncentral chi-squared', you find the [_reference to Laguerre polynomials_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I was not thinking of a reference to the Laguerre polynomials, but how to actually compute the expectation - which is then (apparently) given in terms of the Laguerre polynomials (or just a reference that can be cited for the fact).

Comment: By digging through the references I found: Nuttall, A. H. (1974). Some Integrals Involving the (Q Sub M) Function. Naval Underwater Systems Center, New London Lab., New London, Conn., Tech. Rep. 4755.
Equations (26) and (27) are relevant. I don't think (27) can be used for the mean directly (due to condition N > 1), but (26) and the connection between confluent hypergeometric functions and Laguerre polynomials will do it I think...

Comment: Maybe a lead: follow the two references here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChiDistribution.html (?)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. I had a look at Johnson, N.; Kotz, S.; and Balakrishnan, N. Continuous Univariate Distributions yesterday and didn't find much, but I'll check out: Evans, M.; Hastings, N.; and Peacock, B. "Chi Distribution." §8.3 in Statistical Distributions, 3rd ed. New York: Wiley, p. 57, 2000.

Comment: This is probably very late... but one text I can think of that *might* have this is *A Primer on Linear Models* by Monahan. Note that the non-central $\chi^2$ in this text is defined slightly differently than most other texts, but it should be clear how to modify the proof (if it is there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the two references

[1] Nuttall, A.H. (1974). Some Integrals Involving the (Q Sub M)-Function. Naval Underwater Systems Center, New London, Conn., Tech. Rep. 4755
http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/779846.pdf

[2] Nuttall, A.H. (1975). Some Integrals Involving the $Q_M$ Function. IEEE Transactions on Information Theory 21(1), 95-96
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1055327/

The relevant formulas are (1) and (10) in [1] (or (1) and (26) in [2]).
Realizing that the survival function of $X$ is then given as
\begin{align}
S_X(x) = Q_{d/2}(\lambda,x),
\end{align}
where $\lambda =\Vert \mathbf{m} \Vert_2$, you get via (10) in [1] (or (26) in [2]) that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_0^{\infty}  S_X(x) dx = \frac{2^{1/2}\Gamma(d/2 + 0.5)}{\Gamma(d/2)} \mathbf{M}(-0.5 ; d/2 ; -0.5 \lambda^2).
\end{align}
Here $\mathbf{M}(a; b; z)$ is is the confluent hypergeometric function of the first kind, i.e., $\mathbf{M}(a; b; z) = \phantom{}_1F_1(a; b; z)$.